# How to use firebase google access token/ id token to access google api?

Tags: firebase, google-api, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

After signing in using Google in firebase, I am getting the following credentials of the current user.

```
{  
oauthAccessToken: "ya29.a0AfH6SMAbP.............",  
oauthIdToken: "eyJhbGciOiJSUz................",  
providerId: "google.com",  
signInMethod: "google.com"  
}
```

Now how should I use these access token to connect with Google API? As written [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC5zc.png) in official Firebase docs. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin.

Till now, whatever I have found is using gapi to sign in and using its credentials to sign into firebase. Is there another way round possible?

Comment: Have you tried sending a call manually to the api using the access token you have,  Im not sure the systems are the same will be intersting to hear if it works.

Comment: Are you sure that you are exactly using the code from the doc you refer to in your question? If I am not mistaking, the `credential` object has the following properties, `idToken` and `accessToken`, not `oauthAccessToken` or `oauthIdToken`

Comment: If you `console.log(result.credential.toJSON())` it will give the same results as above.

Comment: @DalmTo I have tried sending a call manually to the api using the access token but ran into errors.

Comment: I think here you can find an example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71129013/givenname-and-familyname-claims-are-missing-in-firebase-idtoken