# Givenname and Familyname claims are missing in firebase idtoken

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am trying to use Firebase to implement google login for our web application.
here is what I have done to get the idtoken :

```
  const google_provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  google_provider.addScope("openid");
  google_provider.addScope("profile");
  google_provider.addScope("email");
  signInWithPopup(auth, google_provider).then((result) =>
    result.user.getIdToken());
```

Although I have added the profile scope still I can not get the `givenname` and `familyname` claims in the `idtoken` ( `email` , `picture` and `name` are avialable)

(I have tried directly to use Google login and there I could see all the profile claims)

What did I miss here ? Did I do something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase ID Token returned by [`getIdToken()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user.md#usergetidtoken) doesn't contain user's Google account information that you are looking for (expect name, profile image, etc). You should use the access code retrieved from sign in result to make request to [Google API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes) to get it.

```
signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
  .then(async (result) => {
    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
    const token = credential.accessToken;

    const response = await fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    })

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  })
```

Comment: Does it mean that I should do the same for other external providers as well ? To implement the authentication flow in our Backend I have created an connet/token endpoint that gets an idetoken validate it baesd on its provider and exchange it for an access token . Other than Google we would also like to add Facebook login in near future

Comment: @Beatles1692 Yes, Firebase's token has similar payload for all provider. Checkout [DecodedToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.decodedidtoken)'s interface. Firebase auth does read name, profile image and email from Google account (or any provider) but the response you are looking for is returned by Google's API. `addScope()` is used to _"Specify additional OAuth 2.0 scopes that you want to request from the authentication provider"_ as mentioned in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin)